# When to use useNativeDriver in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have seen a lot of places talking about using `useNativeDriver` to improve performance or fix issues and from what I have seen is that `useNativeDriver` is always good... but is it? (*Insert VSauce music*)

I know that you [can only animate non-layout properties, things like transform and opacity](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2017/02/14/using-native-driver-for-animated#caveats) so, assuming you can set `useNativeDriver`, will there be a case where it's worst in if you set `useNativeDriver` to `true`?

Because my main intuition is to always set to `true` when possible, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Please use always!

Without `useNativeDriver` to `true`, most of the work happens on the JS thread. If it is blocked the animation will skip frames. It also needs to go through the JS to Native bridge on every frame to update native views.

What the native driver does is move all of these steps to native. Since Animated produces a graph of animated nodes, it can be serialized and sent to native only once when the animation starts, eliminating the need to callback into the JS thread; the native code can take care of updating the views directly on the UI thread on every frame.

With `useNativeDriver` to `true`, there is `no more JS thread` and `no more bridge` involved which means faster animations!